# Netgear WNDR3700v2 - How to email logs using SSL/TLS (port 465)?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have found nothing on how to do this (ed. testing is rather painful).  I am trying to email my Netgear WNDR3700V2 (N600) to my ISP's provided user-email account, but it isn't working.  I know of NO serious email systems that don't require SMTP over SSL/TLS for encrypting the traffic.

Anyone manage to get this to work?  It's such a terrific feature - it's hard to believe I'm not making a false assumption somewhere.

p.s. Clarification on testing.  I can dynamically force email out, but I don't have any useful diagnostics to tell me what problem it's having with the SMTP server.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to email router logs via an old account with RCN network. My problem is getting the router to reliably capture the log files. It seems to work for a while and then shut off.

Comment: How did you get it to do this?